Чи є в літературному вжитку зворот "відсудити частину добробуту"?
Приміром, в англійській мові існує "seize a part of the wealth" в судовому контексті. Але "wealth" може мати більш матеріальне значення (гроші, нерухомість і т. п.), не тільки абстрактне (відчуття забезпеченості), що робить його використання доцільним, а от чи так само вірне вживання тут "добробут"? Аналогічне питання про "достаток". Якщо ні, що вжити натомість?

Wealth не обов'язково перекладається саме як добробут. Я не юрист, але з того, що я бачу в мережі випливає, що правильним перекладом буте майно.

Відчуження частки майна, що перебуває у спільній власності
Особливості припинення права особи на частку у спільному майні
Припинення права власності на частку у спільному майні
Яке майно не підлягає поділу при розірванні шлюбу
Як ділити майно, якщо ви проживали у фактичних шлюбних відносинах?

